# Filter recognition from transfer function

Tags: lowpass-filter, bandpass

I have a filter with this transfer function in the z-plane $H(z)= z^{-k}$. Which type of filter is this (BP,LP,BS)and why?

I have a delay filter with zero/poles equal to zero and the magnitude constant equal to 1, so can I characterize it as an all-pass filter ?

Comment: It's no (frequency-selective) filter at all. If you don't know how to immediately recognize the corresponding impulse response then you should really work on your understanding of the very basics of transfer functions and Z-transform.

Comment: Thanks , I am newbie, can you explain me more things about your statement ? I would aprreciate it

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where to start because the element $z^{-k}$ is one of the three most basic building blocks used in discrete-time filters (like adders or multipliers). This looks like a homework problem, so maybe it would be good to share what you've tried to figure out the answer. It's really hard to give a hint here without just giving the answer.

Comment: I have a delay filter with zero/poles equal to zero and the magnitude constant equal to 1, so can I characterize it as an all-pass filter ?

Comment: @George I'm adding that consideration to your question's body, as it shows your work so far and thus allows people to base their answers on what they know that you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of your comments it appears that you've actually already answered the question. Here are a few remarks and questions that should help you gain some more understanding:

1. If you have a transfer function $H(z)$ (and if you assume that the corresponding system is stable), then the frequency response is obtained by choosing $z=e^{j\omega}$.
2. For $H(z)=z^{-k}$ figure out the magnitude and the phase of $H(e^{j\omega})$.
3. If the magnitude of $H(e^{j\omega})$ does not depend on frequency, what kind of filter have you got?
4. What is the input-output relation of the given system?

Answer (score 0):

A pure delay is also an all-pass filter because

$$ |H(e^{j\omega})| = 1 $$

But it's an FIR version of an APF filter.